# Mailjet Non-Nested Loop Failing

Tags: mailjet

My test email for a Mailjet Template keeps failing in a for loop I am using. Unlike other Mailjet Loop questions on stack overflow, my loops are not nested, and my array is not empty.

The following code keeps failing

In my template, I have two template blocks (for the for and endfor) surrounding a text block. Like below:

```
    {{var:FirstName:""}}

    {% for month in var:MonthList %}

    {{month.Name:""}} {{month.Count:""}}

    {% endfor %}
```

I keep getting:

```
    ERenderError: expression parsing error ## Unknown Identifier: month.Name:"" ## near...
```

When testing the template I am using ExpertMode for updating variables in the Preview Email section.

```
    [{"Month": "March", "Count", 4}]
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong? I've looked into the documentation and read all issues in StackOverflow regarding MailJet loops, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many frustrating hours, I figured out what was wrong as I was about to post this question. Hope it helps someone save some time.

In a for loop, you cannot give a value a default value. For instance {{var:FirstName:""}} is ok outside of the for loop, but {{month.Name:""}} is NOT okay inside the for loop.