# Cannot use logic in Mailjet Template "For" loop

Tags: mailjet

I think it used to let me, not sure what changed? I cannot use logic inside of a Mailjet Template "For" loop. it does not like my `FormatNumber` or `if`

**My Vars:**

```
  "Variables": {
    "CurrentYear": "",
    "OutstandingInvoices": [{"InvoiceNum": "100", "Total": 100.00, "DaysPastDue": "5", "InvoiceMonth": "May", "InvoiceYear": "2021"}],
    "CustomerID": "",
    "CustomerName": "",
    "InvoiceYear": "",
    "InvoiceMonth": ""
  }
}
```

**My Template Code:**

```
{% for invoice in var:OutstandingInvoices %}
{{invoice.InvoiceMonth}} {{invoice.InvoiceYear}} for {{FormatNumber("$#,###.00", invoice.Total)}} {% if invoice.DaysPastDue > 0 %} : {{invoice.DaysPastDue}} days late {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Gives me the following errors:**

(1) ERender Error: Expression Parsing Error: Unknown identifier invoice.Total near FormatNumber("$#,###.00", invoice.Total)

(2) ERender Error: Expression Parsing Error: Unknown identifier invoice.DaysPastDue near invoice.DaysPastDue > 0

**Misc**

I wonder if it is related to not being able to use default values in for loops as well (as per my other question: [Mailjet Non-Nested Loop Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124419/mailjet-non-nested-loop-failing))

So logic of any kind is not allowed in a for loop?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I think its just not allowed? I thought I did have it working once, but maybe not.

Answer (score 7):

after hours of searches, I've found the solution for me :
You need to **wrap for loops** using **`<mj-raw>`** tag.

This should works for you:

```
<mj-raw>{% for invoice in var:OutstandingInvoices %}</mj-raw>
    ...
<mj-raw>{% endfor %}</mj-raw>
```

Comment: It's provide in the documentation, but there's no really clear example. 
https://dev.mailjet.com/email/template-language/mjml/